# multiple image validation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am applying laravel validation for multiple image it works for single iamge upload but can not works for multiple what is mistake done by me?

```
$this->validate($request, array(
     'imagenew.*' => 'required|mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg',
     'image'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
        
));
```

Blade :

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="image" class=" form-control-label">Property Single Image</label>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="form-control-file">
   <span class="text-danger" required>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</span>
    
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <label for="imagenew" class=" form-control-label">Property Multiple Image</label>
    <input type="file" id="imagenew" name="imagenew[]" class="form-control-file" multiple>
  <span class="text-danger" required>{{ $errors->first('imagenew') }}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$validated = $request->validate([
   'imagenew' => 'required|array',
   'imagenew.*' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
   'image'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',
]);
```

Comment: @VikramShinde what is the output of `dd($request->all());` ?